# System reserved formatted to EFi

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, troubleshooting, efi, bootrepair

I was installing Ubuntu with windows already installed so when i tried to install it on my desired drive it gave an error that no efi file system found so I changed my system reserved disk of windows to EFi the installation still didn't completed now that I tried to boot my windows again it said unreadable boot file so I tried formatting the system reserved disk and even tried repairing it using a live windows installation usb after seeing solutions on YouTube but none of it is working can you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure you have followed is not correct.

If your computer uses efi, disable it in the BIOS and use Legacy boot. Disable Secure Boot in the BIOS also. Without knowing the model of your computer it's hard to give more information. Create an Ubuntu live Usb with Rufus and during the installation click erase disks and install Ubuntu(This will erase everything on all of your disks).

Comment: Hp pavilion Notebook au010-wm 15 this is the model of my laptop

Comment: Is there any way I can save my data

Comment: There isn't an option to change to efi in the bios

Comment: There is, if you have 2 hdds you can disconnect the one with your data. if you have 1 had, you can disconnect it and temporarily connect it to a different computer. There is an external USB case which makes your HDD external and you can freely use it with a USB port. it's called Sata 3 to usb or whatever your HDD is using.

Comment: I am working from the phone at the moment, when I get back I will give you the.exact steps and links.

Comment: But all the markets are closed here due to the covid-19 pandemic

Comment: So I can't get anything right now

Comment: The first video is ready. For your laptop it might be only the EFI option. Since you erased the EFI partition, Windows will not boot at all. Now you need to create a new boot partition. ubuntu will do it for you. Try the following. Free up some space(32GB is enough) from partitions that you don't use. Then follow this video and install Ubuntu as the something else option, but give the whole partition onlye the mount / option. I will make the other video as soon as possible. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TphPqKPGgaM

Comment: Thanks alot but just resolved the issue

Comment: Can I ask how did you manage to do that? The exact steps will help others.

Comment: A friend of mine helped me out so not sure but he did everything